# Saving Image Data in a "PNG" File in Java

Tags: java, hex, data-conversion

Displaying an image in base64 is rather simple:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,hexadecimal-code-for-image-here">
```

However, what I'm trying to do is to convert the hexadecimal value received and the save it in a png file so I get the desired picture from the code.

For instance: let's say I have the following code:

```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```

Is there any way I can convert this code to image and then store in a png file in JAVA?

Comment: It's not a hexadecimal (base16) value. It's a base64-encoded value. To save as a PNG file, it's sufficient to base64-decode it and dump the resulting bytes in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer the base64 into byte array and than write it to a png file.

```
byte[] img = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imgBase64);
Files.write(Paths.get("my.png"), img); //As suggested by Joop Eggen
```

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen

Answer (score 2):

Decode base64 image to byte[] then using ImageIO to write to file

```
byte[] imgInBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Img);
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgInBytes);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(in);
File png = new File("ImageAsPNG.png");
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "PNG", png);
```